# How to change the URL identifier of a custom module from backend i.e. system configuration

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I want to give admin the option to change the URL identifier of `MyCustomModule` from backend.

E.g.: www.mydomain.com/identifier

What I did is the following:

In **etc/system.xml**

```
<identifier translate="label">
    <label>SELF URL Identifier</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
**<backend_model>press/config_identifier</backend_model>** // edited after answer
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <comment>(eg: domain.com/identifier)</comment>
</identifier>
```

In **helper/data.php**

```
public function getUrl($identifier = null)
{

    if (is_null($identifier)) {
        $url = Mage::getUrl('').self::getListIdentifier();
    } else {
        //$url = Mage::getUrl(self::getListIdentifier()).$identifier;
**$url = Mage::getUrl(self::getListIdentifier(), array('identifier' => $identifier,'_use_rewrites'=>true)); //edited
        }**
    return $url;
}
```

after that i created a model file identifier.php :

```
class FME_Press_Model_Config_Identifier extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data

{

    protected function _afterSave()

    {

        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {

            $path = $this->getValue();



            // for each $store and $id combination...



            Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')

                ->loadByIdPath('press/'.$store.'/'.$identifier)

                ->setRequestPath($path.'/'.$identifier)

                ->save();

        }

    }

}
```

in config.xml i wrote this:

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <press>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>FME_Pres_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </press>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

and also this is present in my file, m not sure whether it is relevant :

```
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <FME_Press_Override before="Mage_Adminhtml">FME_Press_Override_Admin</FME_Press_Override>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
```

NOTE: I had been told to make some changes in `Controller/Router.php` but I don't know what changes to make.

If you want I can add that code also?

Now, what else should I do?

Comment: Is this based on a previous question here at SO?

Comment: nopx, it is not based on any other question ! but if there z any other related question so plz refer it here, if it is helpful

Comment: "router/controller/action" <- which of these are you trying to make dynamic?

Comment: m trying to make controller dynamic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel changing the application's router is entirely the wrong approach to take. It is messy and can be easily broken if another module overrode it for a similar purpose. The clean way is with URL rewrites.

You want it to be alterable so you cannot use a fixed [XML based rewrite](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller#edit_etcconfig.xml). Instead let's look at the built in rewrite system.

First in your module's **etc/config.xml** file set up a normal controller.

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <MyCustomModule>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Example_MyCustomModule</module>
                <frontName>customlist</frontName>
            </args>
        </MyCustomModule>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Here the front name used is `customlist`, that will always work and shouldn't conflict with any other front name, the rewritten name shall be in addition to this. Now whenever you [generate an URL](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) (perhaps in a helper function) you do so to this apparently fixed front name.

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('customlist', array(
    'id' => $id,    // 'id' will get used in the "target path" later
    '_use_rewrites' => true
));
```

Note that the variable identifier (`$id`) is passed to the `getUrl` function rather than simply appending to it's result. If the function returns an URL with a query (`&`) or fragment (`#`) the identifier could have been appended to the wrong part.

The next step is to create rewrite records for every possible combination of *identifier* and *store*. You probably have a finite number of lists so this is possible, perhaps identifiers are particular to stores so only need to be defined once each. Either loop through all your lists in [an installer script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources/) or have each list create rewrites when it is saved.

```
$path = Mage::getStoreConfig('custom/config/identifier', $storeId);
// Change 'custom/config/identifier' to match the path used in system.xml

$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
               ->loadByIdPath('customlist/'.$store.'/'.$id);
if ($rewrite->getId()) {
    // A rewrite already exists, you might want to skip creating another
    continue;
}

Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setIsSystem(true) // set to false to allow admin to edit directly
    ->setOptions('RP') // Redirect Permanent 301
    ->setIdPath('customlist/'$storeId.'/'.$id) // should never change
    ->setTargetPath('customlist/index/index/id/'.$id) // what gets used
    ->setRequestPath($path.'/'.$id) // the path used in the browser
    ->save();
```

So now if the admin sets the URL path to be "foo/bar" and requests the page "www.mydomain.com/foo/bar/3" it will be rewritten to "customlist/index/index/id/3" and the method `Example_MyCustomModule_IndexController::indexAction()` will be called. The file containing that will of course be **app/code/local/Example/MyCustomModule/controllers/IndexController.php** and the `3` value is retrieved there:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); // 'id' was specified in getUrl()
    // use $id here...
}
```

It should work by now but what if a list is removed? The rewrites need to be updated for each store. Models have a `_beforeDelete` method, override it for your list objects.

```
protected function _beforeDelete()
{
    Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
        ->loadByIdPath('customlist/'.$storeId.'/'.$this->getId())
        ->delete();
    return parent::_beforeDelete();
}
```

Similarly they need to be updated to match changes in configuration.

**etc/system.xml**

```
<identifier translate="label">
    <label>SELF URL Identifier</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <backend_model>myCustomModule/config_identifier</backend_model>
    ...
</identifier>
```

**Model/Config/Identifier.php**

```
class Example_MyCustomModule_Model_Config_Identifier
    extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    protected function _afterSave()
    {
        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {
            $path = $this->getValue();
            // for each $store and $id combination...
            Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->loadByIdPath('customlist/'.$store.'/'.$id)
                ->setRequestPath($path.'/'.$id)
                ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of copy-pasted code here, I have not tested it together so cannot guarantee it will work first time.

Comment: could u plz modify ur answer by just adding which changes to make in which files plzzzz, like u mentioned to make changes in system.xml, config.xml and to create a model for it. But the the code in between these need a lil explanation , mean which file to add this code to.

Comment: the 4 piece of code after 1st piece of code and before system.xml, it needs a lil explanation that in which files i should use this code.

Comment: I tried to be a little more explicit. Where I say things like "for every identifier" I mean to use a loop and get the identifiers you have stored in the database, I don't need to tell you how to do something that simple. Similarly when I use `$store` you should know to find out the store's ID, perhaps in another loop.